# $t$ transcendental $\to t^4 + 7t +2$ transcendental

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that if $t$ is a transcendental number, then $t^4 + 7t +2$ is transcendental. I'm trying to work out a proof where we suppose by contradiction that $t^4 + 7t +2$ is algebraic, so there exists some polynomial with integer coefficients that has it as a root, and then showing this leads to there existing a polynomial that has $t$ as a root (the contradiction). But I'm getting stuck actually trying to write that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $P(t^4+7t+2)=0$, then if you write $Q(X)=P(X^4+7X+2)$, $Q(t)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $t^4 + 7 t + 2$ was algebraic, it would be a root of a polynomial $Q(x)$ of degree $\ge 1$ with integer coefficients, and then $t$ would be a root of the polynomial $Q(x^4 + 7 x + 2)$, which has integer coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

The extension $Q(t^4+7t+2):Q(t)$ is finite.

So if $Q:Q(t^4+7t+2)$ is finite you get

$$|Q:Q(t)|= |Q:Q(t^4+7t+2)|  |Q(t^4+7t+2):Q(t)|<\infty ,$$

a contradiction.